# How to set an uploaded image as 'Base Image', 'Small Image' or 'Thumbnail' with SOAP webservices?

Tags: api, soap, media

I'm looking for a method in the API SOAP (v2) to set an uploaded image like 'Base Image', 'Small Image' or 'Thumbnail', but I can't find one.

I've checked the methods in http://www.magentocommerce.com/api/soap/catalog/catalogProductAttributeMedia/productImages.html
but none of them looks like doing what I want.

Suggestions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can set the base image, small image and thumbnail image like this

```
$proxy->call($sessionId, 'product_media.update', array(
    'Sku',
    $imageFilename,
    array('position' => 2, 'types' => array('image', 'small_image', thumbnail) /* Lets do it main image for product */)
));
```